# How does the querySelector work on elements which are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

```
const element = document.createElement("article");
  // add classes
  element.classList.add("grocery-item");

  const attr = document.createAttribute("data-id");
  attr.value = id;
  element.setAttributeNode(attr);
  element.innerHTML = `<p class="title">${value}</p>
            <div class="btn-container">
              <button type="button" class="edit-btn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>`;
  // append child
  list.appendChild(element);
  // Edit Button
  const editBtn = element.querySelector(".edit-btn");
```

[I am making a grocery list website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnh2.png) and each item in the list like the milk and eggs come under their own article element which is being created in the javascript and I have added the code for that too. Now in the screenshot that I have posted, I have added 3 items in the grocery list, so there are 3 article elements created as per code given under which comes the edit and delete buttons. When I click on the edit button for,suppose eggs,how does it know that I have clicked on the eggs's edit button?

```
const editBtn = element.querySelector(".edit-btn");
```

This line accesses the edit button within the required article element but how does it access the required article element in the first place? There is no querySelector for selecting all the article elements in the rest of the code.

I am not entirely sure how to ask this question, so please do tell me some improvements

Comment: I think you should reduce the text content a bit or atleast change the wording. It is difficult to understand what is (not) happening right now and what do you want to know about it

Comment: Are you able to access the correct element? You might want to show the code you are writing for these multiple elements (5 or 6)

Comment: I think you're referring to `const editBtn = element.querySelector(".edit-btn");`. It'll look for elements with class "edit-btn" that are within your `element` element.

Comment: I have made some changes. I hope it makes some sense now.

Comment: element is the article element. The querySelector looks inside of that for the element you want.

Comment: you can use `event.target`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target